# Getting the base type of a custom type using Reflect

Tags: go, reflection, types

Say I create a custom type in Go:

```
type CustomTime time.Time
```

Using reflection, I'm comparing types, e.g.

```
var foo CustomTime = CustomTime(time.Now())
customType := reflect.TypeOf(foo)

timeType := reflect.TypeOf(time.Now())

if customType == timeType {
    fmt.Println("Is timeType")
} else {
    fmt.Println("Is not timeType")
}
```

This prints "Is not timeType". What I'm trying to do is find a way to see if the **base** type that the custom type uses (i.e. the `time.Time` in `type CustomType time.Time`) is of type `time.Time`.

I've tried using reflect's `Kind()` function, but that returns `struct` for both since `time.Time` is a struct.

Here's a [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/u_-WpRKLjk7) with this code.

Comment: You cannot get time.Time from CustomTime using the reflect package. CustomTime and time.Time share the same underlying type, but otherwise there is no relationship between the types.  Go does not have the concept of a "base" type.

Comment: Why use reflection? Why not a simple type assertion or type switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't exactly, because that's not how types work in Go. In your example, `CustomTime`'s underlying type *isn't Time*; both `CustomTime` and `time.Time` share the same underlying type, which is a `struct` type. [From the docs](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types):

> Each type T has an underlying type: If T is one of the predeclared boolean, numeric, or string types, or a type literal, the corresponding underlying type is T itself. Otherwise, T's underlying type is the underlying type of the type to which T refers in its type declaration.

That means that `CustomTime`s underlying type isn't `time.Time`, it's `time.Time`'s *underlying type*.

You can use [`reflect.Type`'s `ConvertibleTo()` method](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) to see if one type is convertible to another, which is as close as you're likely to get to what you're describing.

Comment: Thanks for the info. What are the functional differences between `reflect.AssignableTo()` and `reflect.ConvertableTo()`? Which would be better in this case?

Comment: @Jordan It depends on your goal.  Neither of the methods will tell you if two types share the same underlying type.  Two types can share the same underlying type and not be assignable (time.TIme and CustomTime are an example).  Two types can be convertible, but not share the same underling type (byte and int are an example). ConvertableTo is the one that returns true for your two types.

Comment: Sorry you're right, `ConvertibleTo` is the correct method in this case. Updated.